# A Yes or No answer in D51 returns a sentence or blank field in A70. A blank or not blank cell in D52 returns a sentence or blank field in A70

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I am trying to create an application that ensures all required fields are completed, but I am having problems getting my formulas to work.

- If the value in cell `D51` is "Yes", then cell `A70` should read "You Must Answer This Question".
- If the value in cell `D51` is No, then cell `A70` should be blank.
- If `D52` is not blank then `A70` should be blank.
- If `D52` is blank then `A70` should read "You Must Answer This Question".

The below formulas work individually but I need all of the criteria above to return an answer in cell `A70`

```
=IF(ISBLANK(D51),"You Must Answer This Question","")

=IF(D51="No","","You Must Answer This Question")
```

Comment: Can D51 be blank?  If so, what happens?  What if D51 is Yes and D52 is not blank?  What if D51 is No and D52 is blank?  BTW, your formulas don't match the description, and this question has the 2nd worse title ever.  How about something like, "Base cell value on conditions in two cells"?

Comment: @Haidee, the [AND](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AND-function-5f19b2e8-e1df-4408-897a-ce285a19e9d9?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1) and [OR](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OR-function-7d17ad14-8700-4281-b308-00b131e22af0?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1) functions would probably be useful in combining your criteria into a single function. But, it seems that your 2 cells could have 4 possible "types" of values: "Yes", "No", some other value, or blank. That's 16 combinations (or 8 if you consider the last 2 equivalent), and a good formula will account for each one of them.

Comment: @fixer1234, you're not going to leave us hanging, are you? What's the worst title?

Comment: @MJH, I should have saved a copy.  It was similar to this one but about twice as long (or maybe it just seemed that way).  :-)

Answer (score 0):

As [fixer1234](https://superuser.com/users/364367/fixer1234) has highlighted in the comments, your question doesn't have enough specific detail to be able to answer it definitively, only by making some assumptions.

So, assuming that the value in `D51` takes precedence over the value in `D52` when it comes to determining what value is placed in `A70`:

```
/-------------------------------------------------------\
|   D51   |     D52     |         A70 Expected          |
|---------+-------------+-------------------------------|
| Yes     | [Any]       | You Must Answer This Question |
| No      | [Any]       | [Blank]                       |
| [Blank] | [Not Blank] | [Blank]                       |
| [Blank] | [Blank]     | You Must Answer This Question |
\-------------------------------------------------------/
```

you could use the following formula in `A70`:

```
=IF(D51="Yes","You Must Answer This Question",IF(D51="No","",IF(ISBLANK(D52),"You Must Answer This Question","")))
```

If this is not your desired logic, perhaps you could better define exactly your expected outcomes based on all possible combinations of values of `D51` and `D52`, so for example if `D51` could contain `Yes`, `No` or be blank and `D52` can either be blank or not blank:

```
/--------------------------------------\
|   D51   |     D52     | A70 Expected |
|---------+-------------+--------------|
| Yes     | [Blank]     |      ?       |
| Yes     | [Not Blank] |      ?       |
| No      | [Blank]     |      ?       |
| No      | [Not Blank] |      ?       |
| [Blank] | [Blank]     |      ?       |
| [Blank] | [Not Blank] |      ?       |
\--------------------------------------/
```

For example, your question does not clearly define what value should appear in `A70` if `D51` is `No` and `D52` is blank - you state that when `D51` is `No`, then `A70` should be blank, but also that when `D52` is blank, `A70` should be `You Must Answer This Question`, so what about when both of these things are true? Does one take precedence over the other (as in my example answer), or is there some other logic you've not told us yet?